# Spring-Webflux:Working with two Mono Responses

Tags: java, kotlin, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to evaluate response which is of type Mono coming from two diffrent services

```
data class Customer(
        val customerId : String ,
        val customerBlance : CustomerBalance,
        val customername : String ,
        val customerRefNo : String
)


data class CustomerBalance(
        val totalAmount : Double ,
        val totalCreditAmount : Double ,
        val totalDebitAmount : Double
)
```

Here I have two services one returns customer information and another returns customer balance
both emit Mono of objects.

firstService returns Mono which I need to set on CustomerBalance object.

second service returns Mono which I need to set on CustomerBalance object.

I tried to write below code was able to evaluate first mono ,but having trouble iterating second mono to set the CustomerBalance object.

```
 class CustomerInformationService
   {
        fun getCustomerInfomation( firstObject:Mono<Any>, second:Mono<Any>):Mono<Customer>
        {
                second.map { getCustomerInfo(it) }
        }

    private fun getCustomerInfo(it : Any?):Customer {
            return Customer()
    }
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I follow what you're trying to do, but normally in a reactive flow you don't pass around the Monos but the actual values and then chain the different service calls after each other. When you have all the info you need you can map it to the object you wish to return.

So you would write something like:

```
fun getCustomerInformation(customerId: String) :Mono<Customer> {
    return customerId.toMono()
        .flatMap { getCustomerInfo(it) }
        .flatMap { getCustomerBalance(it) }
        .map { ObjectYouWantToReturn }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this by using `Mono.zipWith(Mono)`